# How to share Redux logic between React and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a boiler plate for either back-end and front-end (web with React and mobile with React Native).

I would like the front-end to have a shared directory for Redux files.

But when I try to reach the shared folder from react :

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../../redux/reducers/user
>   which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports
>   outside of src/ are not supported.

So how can I achieve this if it's forbiden to access anything that is out of /src

Also I would like to avoir making another project for the shared part

Thanks by advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried symlinks?

On mac:

```
ln -s <dest> <link>
```

On windows:

```
mklink link destination
```

Comment: Just keep on mind that they must be a relative ones